# Mac Terminal, find and replace spaces command

Tags: macos

i'm writting a list of commands within an Atom plugin, one of the commands changes the terminals working directory.

However my issue is that if there is a space within the URL it will not work, it gets the directory location from the current working path, so I can't back slash the spaces manually.

You can set variables within the terminal, so is there a way to replace the spaces and back slash them within a terminal command?

** Edit: **
I get the following error code:

> The files /Users/imac/Dropbox/_themev2-folder-1157, /Users/imac/WE,
>   /Users/imac/FINANCE, /Users/imac/POOR, and /Users/imac/CREDIT do not
>   exist.

This is the code, `%(project.root)` get's replaced with the project file path.

```
"command": [
  "pkill -9 gulp",
  "echo 'Quit: Gulp process terminated!'",
  "echo 'Start: New gulp process started, please wait...'",
  "open %(project.root)",
  "cd \"%(project.root)\"",
  "gulp"
]
```

** Edit 2 ** 
Quotes work now. Please add as an answer.

Comment: Put double quotes round the items, like this `"url with spaces"` and if that doesn't work, please show your code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to backslash escaping troublesome characters (such as spaces) you can enclose the entire path/parameter in double quotes, so you might use:

```
someCmd "/path with space/file with space.txt"
```

rather than

```
someCmd /path\ with\ space/file\ with\ space.txt
```